# Is there any way to identify filter in creating new Filter Activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, mobileconnect, contactbuilder

I have this situation when I saved a filter to list in either Mobile Studio or Contact Builder with the name of a list (pic.1 above). When I try to create a Filter Activity in Automation Studio for further use, the UI only shows auto generated name of the filter without any of identical name or string from the list (pic.2 below). The question here would be how to identify the filter I have saved in pic.1?

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile lists are not filtered activities. What you want to do if go to automation studio create a new automation and use the step '[Refresh Mobile List](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_refresh_mobile_filtered_list.htm&type=5)'

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, I forgot this thanks for your information